# Активация кнопок в angular

Tags: angularjs

Никак не могу сообразить.Есть несколько buttons на странице, как сделать так, что бы при клике по кнопке у нее появлялся класс active. Причем только у нее одной а не у всех.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать так: у вас есть поле в модели `selectedTab`, по клику вы задаете текущее значение. Аналогично можно использовать другие удобные Вам идентификаторы.

```
<ul ng-init="selectedTab = 'users'">
<li ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'users'}" ng-click="selectedTab = 'users'"><a href="#users" >Users</a></li>
<li ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'items'}" ng-click="selectedTab = 'items'"><a href="#items" >Items</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Вот спасибо!!!!